# Dell 2970 with H700 and WD RED SAS-2 WD3001FYYG: Compatible? (YES)

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, h700

we have an old 2970 and 5 SAS-2 WD3001FYYG 3TB SAS disks. We want to replace the PERC 6/i RAID Controller with the Dell H700.

Is this a working setup? 
Can I simply replace the Perc 6/i with the H700 or do I need to replace cables or something as well?

The disks are empty, so no migration is required.

Thank you for the information!

Comment: The PE 2970 isn't listed as a supported server for that controller.

Comment: I know, but in the end, it is just a SAS controller. I know it works with the 2950 (not supported). The backplane seems to have SAS connectors, while the H700 has mini SAS. So different cables are required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime: We have purchased the PERC H700 controller.

- it does not fit into the RAID slot, due to the presence of a holder in the 2970 case and a unlucky placed cooler on the controller.
- the controller works in the PCIe slots, problem now is getting cables of proper size.
- You need at least 75cm long cables of type SFF-8484 - SFF-8087. This was not easy to get for me. I purchased two cables on amazon. Cables 50cm are many, but longer is hard to get. I found two companies, one is Lindy, that cable is no longer available, and There were only two left to buy. I paid 50€/cable.

  - There is a cable from DELL that looks right, but has only (2) disks connected on the backplane connector. I fell for that and it took me some time to realise, that the rightside connector on the backplane was not broken, but the cable addressed the disks 6 and 7, which are not there :-P.
- The cables must have a straight connector on both sides!
- The controller firmware must be updated to the latest firmware (mine was already), otherwise, chances are that the controller has no 3TB disk support.
- Looking from the front, the left connector on the backplane is serving slots 0,1,2,3, the right connector serves the 4 and 5.
- The write cache battery is clipped in the very front of the case, but the controller is now in the far end - connector cable is way to short. I have fiddled around and placed the battery outside the 2970 case and fiddled the cable through the slots - looks tacky but works. The battery is fine for the controller.

I have successfully connected the disks with the controller and created my raid. So far it is not in heavy load condition but it ran some days in near zero load without trouble.